# Regex Find Anchor in String

Tags: regex

```
preg_match('.*<a\b(?=\s)(?=(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*)*?\shref=['"]([^"]*)['"]?)(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"\s]*)*"\s?\/?>/m',$data,result);
```

how can i work with

> php regex

find anchor link here.
This giving syntax error. how can we fix that.
you can see here working status.

> http://www.rubular.com/r/G5F6AD5UyL

Comment: You lack the very basics of PHP, read the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the quotes in your regex - in Ruby that's not necessary because regexes are first-class objects with their own literal syntax, but not in PHP. Also, you need to add delimiters:

```
preg_match('~.*<a\b(?=\s)(?=(?:[^>=]|=\'[^\']*\'|="[^"]*"|=[^\'"][^\s>]*)*?\shref=[\'"]([^"]*)[\'"]?)(?:[^>=]|=\'[^\']*\'|="[^"]*"|=[^\'"\s]*)*"\s?/?>~m',$data,result);
```